# Speed of a 16384-bit RSA key

Tags: rsa

I don't think it makes much sense to use RSA keys to authenticate the establishment of symmetric keys with strengths less than their own. From what I know, a 16384-bit RSA key's strength is roughly equal to a 256-bit symmetric key's strength. But how long would the operations take for encryption and decryption/signing?

Comment: That very strongly depends on the runtime. Java 8 for instance doesn't sport CPU provided RSA acceleration by itself. Java 9 does. And that's just different *versions* of the same runtime.

Answer (score 3):

RSA private key operations with $b$-bit keys scale as $\Theta(b^3)$ while public key operations scale as $\Theta(b^2)$. The reason public key operations are faster is that you can use a small constant $e$, e.g. $65537$, while $d$ will be as large as the modulus. So private key operations with a 16384-bit key will take about 512 times as long as for a 2048-bit key, and public key operations will take about 64 times as long.

That's pretty painful and you probably don't want to do it. Consider whether you really need a 256-bit security level; the only reason we use symmetric keys that size is for insurance against partial breaks and because that insurance comes pretty cheaply. With asymmetric crypto it's not so cheap any more. If for whatever reason you decide you really *do* need that kind of security, consider instead using a large elliptic curve such as Ed448-Goldilocks.

Comment: How about brainpoolP512r1 or brainpoolP512t?

Comment: Also: it you stick to RSA with two prime factors of the public modulus, each will exceed the typical capability of hardware accelerators and tested-secure implementations, thus the very feasibility in secure conditions may be lost. A reasonable compromise could be using multi-prime RSA with 4 factors of 4096 bit each. If that's supported by the hardware (and a lot of lesser ifs) that should allow 16384-bit RSA private key operations to run only about 16 times slower than 4096-bit RSA private key operations with CRT and two factors, beating the $\Theta(b^3)$ scaling by a factor of about 4.

Comment: With server/desktop CPU's (which now sport instructions that can accelerate RSA operation) 16Ki private key operations could be possible. You'd probably not want to be waiting for a machine *generating* such a key pair though. Furthermore you can ask yourself if using such a large key size without a certified hardware module makes sense in the first place.